# Autofill with python

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to build a bot with python. I want python to act as an autofill and I made this part of programm :

```
> ord_billing_name=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cart- 
address"]/fieldset/div[1]').click()
> ord_billing_name.send_keys(buyerName)
```

(The programm to get to the website works)

But python displays :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

And the case is not filled on the website. 
Please, can someone tell me what is wrong ? 
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.click()` doesn't return anything but you are assigning the return to `ord_billing_name`. You need to separate this into 3 lines... first line is grabbing the element and assigning it to the variable. The other two lines are `click()` and `send_keys()`.

```
ord_billing_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cart-address"]/fieldset/div[1]')
ord_billing_name.click()
ord_billing_name.send_keys(buyerName)
```

Comment: Yes you are totally right. It works perfectly now. But I thought it was faster, this process is very slow as autofill. Thank you !

Comment: Setting a variable to an element and then clicking it on a separate line isn't going to be a difference you will see. It's probably on the order of <25ms difference if any.

Comment: If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

Comment: @DavyJacquemaard : Go through this link, it good to accept answer which is helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer